# Use of Dyanmic Linear Models in Interrupted Time Series

Tags: intervention-analysis, dlm, segmented-regression

I've been undertaking research in which I use an Interrupted Time Series [ITS] approach to attempt to quantify the effect of a policy intervention.

An ITS approach segments the data into two periods, representing pre- and post-policy. The most common approach applies an OLS or GLS regression to each segment and quantifies the effect as either the difference in intercept and slope of the 2 models **OR** uses said model to predict the values in the post policy period, based upon the continuation of the pre-policy model unaltered. However, an alternative approach allows for the use of ARIMA models.

I'm a little confused as I'm not sure how the ARIMA approach would be used. I assumed only based upon the  predicted values, but wondered whether a similar comparative approach could be used where the two models are directly compared?? I had originally used a Dynamic Linear Model to model the pre-policy period and predict a future post-policy period, but this has proven problematic.

As such, I wondered if there was a means by which to compare the two models fit to each segment [similarly to the ARIMA method if such was plausible]?

If anyone has any ideas it would be hugely appreciated [as I'm dying here!]!

Comment: Yours is a very general question. Since you mention dynamic linear models, I think you may find of interest this paper, which some colleagues and I authored a while ago: Y. LLORENS, F. TUSELL, A. CANUT, H. BARRASA, E. CORRAL, A. MARTIN, A. RODRIGUEZ (2019) Antibiotic susceptibility trend before and after long-term use of selective digestive decontamination: a 16 year ecological study, *Journal of Antimicrobial Chemoterapy,* doi:10.1093/jac/dkz186 .

Answer (score 1):

There are many R packages that can fit ARIMA models to break-point data. I compiled an overview of some of them here: https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html. Fewer of these can do a model comparison.

I created the mcp package for this (an several other) purposes, so you may want to check out the docs on [model comparison in mcp](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/comparison.html). One advantage of Bayesian methods is that they inherently penalize more complex model due to their larger predictive space, whereas you have to do some tricks using frequentist methods. As of version 0.2, `mcp` only does AR(N) models - not MA(N) or ARIMA(N). From your description, your two models would be:

```r
# The two models
model_break = list(
    y ~ 1 + x + ar(1),
    ~ 1 + x
)
model_null = list(y ~ 1 + x + ar(1))

# Fit them
library(mcp)
fit_break = mcp(model_break, data)
fit_null = mcp(model_null, data)

# Compare them
fit_break$loo = loo(fit_break)
fit_null$loo = loo(fit_null)
loo::loo_compare(fit_break$loo, fit_null$loo)
```

## Incorporating knowledge about the change point location

If you know the break point exactly, you can fix the prior to a particular value, indicating 100% certainty in that value:

```r
prior_break = list(cp_1 = 211.5)
fit_break = mcp(model_null, data, prior_break)  # override default priors
```

If you know it approximately (e.g., when the policy was changed but not when the effects occur), you could set a lower bound:

```r
prior = list(cp_1 = "dunif(211.5, MAXX)")  #
```

By default, `mcp` infers the changepoint with a weak prior.

## See model fits

There are several views of the model fits:

- Use `summary(fit)` for a numerical summary of the parameter estimates.
- Use `plot(fit)` for a visualization of the whole model and it's fit to data.
- Use `plot_pars(fit)` to see posterior distributions for individual parameters.

`fit` would then be either `fit_break` or `fit_null` from above. These functions have a lot of options so check out their docs.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, that was really useful. In my instance I am aware of an exact date, but expect a lagged effect [and have removed the transition period from the models]. My data is a univariate time series [year and data].........I assume therefore that I plug 'year into y and the ' dependent variable' into x ?? Also....how would you read the outcome? Thanks again

Comment: @user284031, the right-hand side (`y`) is the dependent variable and the left-hand side (`x`, etc.) are the predictors as in all regression. I've updated the answer on how to see the results using `summary()` and `plot()`.